# Halting via systemd service

Tags: linux, shell, systemd, shutdown

**Short version:** How can I get a systemd controlled service to trigger an immediate shutdown?

---

I have a daemon empowered to do arbitrary things in response to certain events via a (fork/exec'd) shell script ending with

```
exec halt -p
```

Or more specifically, `exec $@`, but in this case `$@` is `halt -p`.  I've also tried:

- `shutdown now`
- `systemctl halt`.

While this works, there seems to be a problem that causes the shutdown, which would normally only take a few seconds, to take several minutes. I suspect it is because systemd is waiting on a child process of a service (the `halt` itself) that doesn't politely die upon request.  I.e., it is sort of a snake chasing its own tail scenario.

The service has no `ExecStop` and is `Type=forking`.

Comment: Normally, having `RemainAfterExit=yes` in the `[Service]` section of the Unit should stop it being killed on halt, but perhaps it interferes with your `Type=forking` detection of failure.

Comment: @meuh By the man page what that does is specify *"whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited"*, which seems very different from stopping them from *"being killed on halt"* (a bit oxymoronical).  There should be some means by which a systemd service can trigger a shutdown.  Anyway, it did not work in this case.

Comment: You could look through `man systemd.kill` and perhaps reduce `TimeoutStopSec=90` or try `SendSIGKILL=no`.

Comment: @meuh \O/ So `KillMode=process` from that man page works (I imagine `KillMode=none` would also work, but since the daemon isn't concerned about orphans, it can be stopped).  I've edited this a bit since realizing the problem was a *delay*, presumably in "the snake chasing its tail" (see above).  Anyway, I think you get what's going and if you want to put that into an answer you can have a tick from me.   No rush and if not, no worries, I'll do it later.

Answer (score 1):

In `man systemd.kill` there's the following explanation of the `KillMode` option:

> `KillMode=`
>
> Specifies how processes of this unit shall be killed. One of **control-group, process, mixed, none.**
>
> If set to **control-group,** all remaining processes in the control group of this unit will be killed on unit stop (for services: after the stop command is executed, as configured with `ExecStop=`).

This implies a customized `ExecStop` all by itself will not help, but:

> If set to **process**, only the main process itself is killed.
>
> If set to **none**, no process is killed. In this case, only the stop command will be executed on unit stop,

So, `ExecStop` could be used in conjunction with `KillMode=none`.  This would be necessary if the daemon started persistent processes, to target them but not the `halt`.  In my case it doesn't, and the daemon itself has a `SIGTERM` handler and does not wait on children, so needs no special cleanup.  Hence adding `KillMode=process` to the `[Service]` block solved the problem; the daemon is stopped, leaving the `halt` to complete, and the system shuts down as it normally does in a few seconds.